I can't pass data to the component in Laravel
I'm trying to pass data to the components using directly to the Blade component (using @props).
As a first step I put the following code in notification.blade.php:


@props([
    'type' => 'info',
    'message'
])

<div class="alert alert-{{ $type }} notification">
    {{ $message }}
</div>



Now in the test.blade.php view I put the following code (:type and :message are data passed to the component)


<x-notification type="success" message="Success! Your changes have been saved" />

<x-notification type="warning" message="Error! Something went wrong" />

<x-notification :type="$type" :message="$message" />



I get the following error:
Undefined variable $message on notification.blade.php
Can someone help me please?

Please check if the error is coming from the test.blade.php where you are passing $message or the component notification.blade.php.

This would indicate that $message is not defined in test.blade.php. But you should confirm that for us so we can better answer the question.

@Anil I get error on notification.blade.php

@geertjanknapen I get error on notification.blade.php

@el_codigo_me_encanta Please check if you have $message defined or initialized anywhere in test.blade.php. Since you are adding notification component to the test blade and passing $message from there, you need to make sure $message is defined
